# How can I connect Ubuntu Server 10.04 VM without router from my local computer?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, putty, remote-access, ubuntu-server

I installed VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 on it. I want to connect from my Windows 7 desktop with PuTTY to my server. I don't have a router, just a modem. On the settings in my VM I choose: Network » Enable Network » Bridged Adapter.

I found the IP address in `ifconfig`. PuTTY can't connect to the server. Why? How can I connect to the Ubuntu Server 10.04 VM from my local computer?

Comment: Don't use bridged networking if you don't have a router.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple machines, whether physical or virtual, on a network without a router is inconvenient in a number of ways, but assuming only the host needs access to the Ubuntu server and the server does not need to have access to the internet, the easiest way would probably be to set up a seperate virtual network consisting of two software interfaces. VirtualBox should be able to configure both automatically. Based on a quick look in the [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly), I believe this function is called 'Host-only networking'.